# Subir un archivo desde react a node con una ruta de directorio de destino

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, axios, multer

estoy intentando subir un archivo al servidor utilizando react y node.js la forma de subirlo del lado del servidor utilizó multer. Cada usuario tiene un directorio dentro del servidor, me gustaría guardar el archivo dentro del directorio del usuario pero para eso necesito mandar la ruta del directorio destino, y no se como hacerlo, en mi formulario upload tengo lo siguiente:

```
state = {
      selectedFile: null,
        }

fileSelectedHandler = event => {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        });
    }
fileUploadHandler = () => {
        const fd = new FormData();
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };
            fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile)
            axios.post('upload', fd, config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
    }
```

Y en mi código de node con multer tengo lo siguiente

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('noren')

router.post('/upload',function(req, res) {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        } else if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        return res.status(200).send(req.file)

    })

});
```

Intente mandar la ruta en axios y recuperarla en node

```
fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile)
            axios.post('uploadFile', fd,{data:{path: this.props.path}} config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
```

o

```
fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile,this.props.path)
            axios.post('uploadFile', fd, config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
```

También intente agregando otra clave valor en el FormData.append() pero no se como recuperar la clave en node. Espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

un ejemplo: 
en el  /controller/user.js :

```
function uploadImage(req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.id
    var file_name = 'No subido...'

    if (req.files) {
        var file_path = req.files.image.path
        var file_split = file_path.split('/')
        var file_name = file_split[2]
        var ext_file = file_name.split('.')
        var file_ext = ext_file[1]

        if (file_ext == 'jpg' || file_ext == 'gif' || file_ext == 'png') {
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { image: file_name }, (err, userUpdated) => {
                if (!userUpdated) {
                    res.status(404).send({ message: 'No se ha podido actualizar el usuario' })
                } else {
                    res.status(200).send({ user: userUpdated })
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'La extension no es correcta' })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'No se ha subido ninguna imagen' })
    }
}


function getImageFile(req, res) {
    var imageFile = req.params.imageFile
    var path_file = './uploads/users/' + imageFile
    fs.exists(path_file, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_file))
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'no existe la imagen' })
        }
    })
}
```

luego en routes/user.js :

```
var md_upload=multipart({uploadDir:'./uploads/users'})

var UserController=require('../controllers/user')
api.post('/upload-Image-user/:id',[md_auth.ensureAuth,md_upload],UserController.uploadImage)
```

en el app.js

```
//cargar rutas
var user_routes= require('./routes/user')
//rutas base
app.use('/api',user_routes);
```